# Extract specific text from text file using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to extract specific text from a text file using batch code. The file from which I need to extract data will have multiple lines of text and the number of lines will vary, which means the position of the indicators will change as well. Here's a sample of the text file:

File 1:

```
<File>
<General>
   <Primary_1>1.2.3.4.5</Primary_1>
   <Secondary_2>9.8.7.6.5</Secondary_2>
</General>
<Main_List>
   <Details="Title" One="C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5" Two="I" Three="4"/>
</Main_List>
</File>
```

I've gone through some manipulation already and extracted the lines that contain the data I need from the text file and saved it to two separate text files so I end up with this:

File 2:

```
   <Primary_1>1.2.3.4.5</Primary_1>
```

File 3:

```
<Details="Title" One="C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4" Two="A" Three="5"/>
```

So, from the two files above (file 2 & file 3), I need to be able to extract two values. The first being between the |Primary_1| and |/Primary_1| indicators...in this case I would need to pull the "1.2.3.4.5" value. The second being the value after the |Details="| and before the |" One=| indicators...in this case I would need to pull the "Title" value.

I searched around and couldn't find anything that quite fit the bill. The closest I found was the "...on the same line..." code ([Extract part of a text file using batch dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042909/extract-part-of-a-text-file-using-batch-dos)), but I kept getting errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when both lines are in file.txt

It works for the txt as given, if TABs aren't in the file.

```dos
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<> " %%a in ('find "<Primary_1>" ^< "file.txt" ') do echo "%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('find "<Details =" ^< "file.txt" ') do SET "xtitle=%%a"
SET ntitle=%xtitle:~1%
SET xtitle="%xtitle%"
ECHO +%ntitle%+ or +%xtitle%+ - your choice...
```

There is a more robust method using a helper batch file if your wanted text contains spaces.

(little tickle by Magoo - allows spaces in the quoted "Title" string - but I don't know whether the requirement is for quoted or unquoted variable contents...so you get both. (no extra charge)

Comment: The first "for" line worked perfectly and pulled the correct information...the "1.2.3.4.5" data. However, the second "for" line pulled "Details" instead of "Title". Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: My bad. Looks like I missed a space in the third file as follows:

<Details ="Title" One="C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4" Two="A" Three="5"/>

How would I modify the delims in the second for statement to accommodate this space? The space is between the word Details and the equals sign. Thanks again.