# Extract substring at certain position from text file and assign to environment variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file `text.txt`. The content of the file is:

> ```
> --a-- W32i   APP ENU    12.0.1.61053 shp
> ```

I need to extract (via command line) the portion `12.0.1.61053`.

This value is in the first line, at position 25 to 36.
I need to insert this value into an environment variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract specific text from text file using batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260587/extract-specific-text-from-text-file-using-batch). Please take the time to do at least a basic search for similar existing questions before posting a new one. Thanks.

Comment: Also SO is a programmer-to-programmer website for programmers to help other programmers solve problems. So you should show what you've tried and what problems you are having with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward. The code assumes that text.txt is in the same directory as your script.

```
@echo off

:: Get the first line of text.txt and store the entire thing in a variable
set /p first_line=<text.txt

:: Get an 11-character substring starting at position 25 (substrings start at 0)
set first_line=%first_line:~24,12%

echo %first_line%
```

Comment: Indeed. This is what happens when you rush and compensate for off-by-one numbers in too many places.