# Mass extract part of a text file using Windows batch

Tags: batch-processing, text-extraction, txt

I have thousands of txt files that are actually in JSON format.
Each file has the same string, with different values, namely:

```
"Name":"xxx","Email":"yyy@zzz.com"
```

I want to extract the values of these two strings from all the txt files that I put in the same folder.

I've found these lines of code:
[Extract part of a text file using Windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042909/extract-part-of-a-text-file-using-windows-batch)
but it only applies to one txt file. Whereas what I need is, it can execute all files in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FORFILES` command, to loop through each file,

Syntax
`FORFILES [/p Path] [/m SrchMask] [/s] [/c Command] [/d [+ | -] {date | dd}]`

From the following webpage,

https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html